# php - Slim $app->request->getBody() is always empty

Tags: php, frameworks, request, slim

Like i said, when i'm trying to get the body of the request in a PUT method it is empty. Here is the code that i'm using the get the body.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    parse_str($app->request()->getBody(), $request_params);
}
```

I can get the params by `$app->request()->params('key');`
But get the full body returns always null.

Comment: what if you var_dump?

Comment: @izk  the result is this: array(0) {}

Comment: returns nothing? There is no data in the array.

Arrays and objects are explored recursively by var_dump, so if any data at all was present, it would show up.

Comment: @izk perfect, i understand that. The issue that i'm having is in my REST api, I'm sending put params and I'm able to get it using `$app->request()->params('key');` but when i'm trying to get the full body it's returning null.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct way. Slim has an http request for PUT.

```
$app = \Slim\App();
$app->put('/url', function($request, $response){
      $request = $request->getParsedBody();
});
```

Then you can access parameters just like an array.

ie.
`$key = $request['key'];`